# lilypond - how to hide an accidental

Tags: lilypond

I am writing a JS Bach manuscript in lilypond. I *want* to just write what he wrote without adding any editorial stuff... and I am kind of struggling with accidentals. In (at least) this manuscript (BWV 1001) he writes down all accidentals. So, the key of his manuscript is F major (or D minor, anyway) though it's actually G minor. So most of the times he is writing an E, it's actually an E flat... and so he writes down **all** E flats in a single bar. So suppose he writes this:

```
ees ees ees ees
```

If I rendered that, we would get only the first E to have the flat, and then lilypond would skip it on the following ones.... So, in order for it to include the flats in the other Es, I write this:

```
ees ees! ees! ees!
```

Which works like a charm. However, in one of the bars, he has a *natural* D (and it's a natural because in the manuscript it has *no* accidental written down) that is following a few D flats in the same bar:

Suppose, it's like this:

```
des des des d
```

I could use the same trick for the second and 3rd Ds

```
des des! des! d
```

But lilypond will still write the *natural* on the final note, which I want to avoid, because Bach didn't write it.

As a workaround, I could write this:

```
des des! des! des
```

Which would *skip* the accidental on the final note, but I would rather have a D.

Is there a simple trick to pull it off?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`\accidentalStyle forget` at the start of your music should do the trick.  The  notation reference has an extensive list of accidental styles.  It usually is best to just write the notes and let LilyPond figure out what to print, and there are various different means available for that.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to get rid of anything, there is a simple way. Just use `\hide` or `\omit`. (The difference between them is that if `\hide` is used, there will still be some empty space where the thing would normally be. If `\omit` is used, the space will not be there.)

So doing `des des! des! \once\omit Accidental des` does the trick. You can experiment with it in a [lilybin](http://lilybin.com/w3ldvt/1) (a web app that can show and edit Lilypond snippets and compile them into scores which is displayed side-by-side with the snippet).